# VS2022 Stop Profiler

Tags: visual-studio

Working with the new VS2022 just installed Monday, first day of release.  Saw a video of the Profiler and thought I would try one.  (Alt-F2).  When you start the Diagnostic Tools gets suspended.  That I can understand.  Now I cannot stop the profiler.  Exiting, rebooting the computer I still do not get the Diagnostic Tools back.

When I try and start another tool I get:  "The collection session cannot be launched because another on is currently active."  How do I stop the current one???

You can learn more about the Profiller here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Shoud note I am mostly working on WPF in C#.

Comment: From what I can find this is a bug in VS.  Still working on solution.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this issue. Is there any VS related process(background process) listed in Windows Task Manager? If yes, please try to select it and end the task. Besides, I suggest you try to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#how-to-repair), and check some running applications and make sure they will not affect Profiler, for example antivirus software. Disable them temporarily if necessary. I would also suggest you try to create a new WPF project and run the Profiler to see whether the same issue happens again.

Answer (score 3):

Since I never got response to it, I used the sledgehammer approach.  I uninstalled VS2022 and then reinstalled it. It now works fine.  I have been afraid to try another Diagnostic Tool.

Comment: Frustrating.  I'm getting this error in VS2019, and unfortunately I'm not able to re-install.  Microsoft's dev tooling on Windows is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cperformance-profiler-problem/208795),

> The Performance Profiler will not work while a debugging session is active with the Diagnostics Tools window in operation.

To disable the Dignostics window

Menu => Tools => Options => Debugging => General => Uncheck "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging"

After that the Profiling worked fine.

[image]